# Optionally redirect a content to another url?

Tags: 7, redirection

I'm using drupal 7.  I have a content type called News Item.   On my home page, I have a block+view that lists the most recent news items.  What is shown is the title of the news item, a brief description, and a read more link to the news item.   When a person clicks on the read more link, it takes them to a page that displays the entire news item.

I want the ability to specify a redirect on some news items.  If a news item has a redirect, whenever a person clicks on the read more link in the home page, they will be redirected to a different url, NOT the url of the actual news item.  And if a person types in the url of the actual news item, they will be redirected to the different url instead.

How do I implement this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a field called url_redirect to the relevant content types.  Then in my theme_process_html() function of template.php, i added the following code:

```
if(isset($variables['node']->field_url_redirect))
{
  if(is_array($variables['node']->field_url_redirect))
  {
    $temp = current($variables['node']->field_url_redirect);
    if(is_array($temp))
    {
      $temp = current($temp);
      if(is_array($temp))
      {
        $url_redirect = $temp['value'];
        if(preg_match('/^\w[\w\d_-]*\./',$url_redirect))
        {
          $url_redirect = 'http://'.$url_redirect;
        }
        else
        {
          $url_redirect = '/'.$url_redirect;
        }
        if(isset($variables['logged_in']))
        {
          $url_redirect = '/redirect?node='.$variables['node']->nid.'&rurl='.urlencode($url_redirect);
          if(isset($variables['node']->current_version_id))
          $url_redirect .= '&v='.$variables['node']->current_version_id;
        }
        header('Location: '.$url_redirect);
        exit;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could handle this in a views row level template file.

First set up a field for the redirect which is optional. Then add it to your view. Create the appropriate views row template file. In your template file print out the fields individually adding a bit of logic around the read more link:

```
<?php if ($fields['news_url']): ?>
  <?php print $fields['news_url']; ?>
<?php else: ?>
  <?php print $fields['readmore']; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Obviously the field names are wrong but hopefully this gives you the idea.